# Wallpaper slideshow without manual intervention

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wallpaper, appearance

I wanted to create a desktop wallpaper slideshow with my own set of images as described in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow) using shotwell but faced certain problems

- once photos are selected from shotwell for slideshow ; it continues using even those images which have been deleted manually from the specified folder after selection of photos
- similarly when photos are added they aren't automatically picked up for slideshow

In short
How to set up the slideshow in such a way that photos are automatically picked or removed ?I will prefer scripts over any extra apps if possible or apps if they are from well known authentic sources .

Answer (score 1):

Shotwell may not be the best utility for this. As far as I know, Ubuntu uses Xorg so we can use a command line program called `feh`.

Excerpt from the man page (`man feh`):

> feh is a mode-based image viewer.  It is especially aimed at command line users who need
>   a fast image viewer without huge GUI dependencies, though it can also be started by
>   (graphical) file managers to view an image.  By default (unless arguments or a filelist
>   are specified) feh displays all files in the current directory.

Installation on Debian-based systems usually looks like this:

```
~# apt install feh
```

To set wallpapers let's look at the manpage again.

> feh can also be used as a background setter.  Unless you pass the --no-fehbg option, it
>   will write a script to set the current background to ~/.fehbg.  So to have your back‐
>   ground restored every time you start X, you can add "sh ~/.fehbg &" to your X startup
>   script (such as ~/.xinitrc).  As of feh 2.13, this script is executable, so "~/.fehbg &"
>   will work as well.

Later in the manpage:

> --bg-center
>
> Center the file on the background.  If it is too small, it will be surrounded by
>   a black border
>
> --bg-fill
>
> Like --bg-scale, but preserves aspect ratio by zooming the image until it fits.
>   Either a horizontal or a vertical part of the image will be cut off
>
> --bg-max
>
> Like --bg-fill, but scale the image to the maximum size that fits the screen
>   with black borders on one side.
>
> --bg-scale
>
> Fit the file into the background without repeating it, cutting off stuff or
>   using borders.  But the aspect ratio is not preserved either
>
> --bg-tile
>   Tile (repeat) the image in case it is too small for the screen

So, you could use this in some sort of repeating script:

(just a proof of concept, not real programming)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import time

files = [
        '1.jpg', // Perhaps you could have a listing of ls here, and parse that.
        '2.jpg',
        'file.jpg'
]
while True:
        for i in files:
                os.system('feh ' + files[i] + ' --bg-fill')
                time.sleep(120)
```

I hope this helps point you in the right direction.

PS: Do note that I am an `i3` user and this is how I set my wallpaper. I hope I could help someone.